# Applying Transformation after rotation animation of textview in Android

Tags: android, transformation, android-animation, textview

I am performing a simple `rotate animation` on a `textview`. Animation is performed as required but `transformation is not applied`.

My Animation Code:

```
Animation animation = new RotateAnimation(0.0f,90.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f);
animation.setDuration(200);
animation.setFillEnabled(true);
animation.setFillAfter(true);
myTextView.startAnimation(animation);
```

Now if `text = "Testing"...` then after animation, if i touch on lower part of textview (or touch "g") it won't repond.. but if i touch the middle part of rotated textview, it responds... After again pressing the rotate button, the textview animation starts from the old position. So I guess, transformation is not getting applied.

Answer (score 0):

Animation is just animation, it draws the View in the different place. It doesn't mean the view is in the different place. To put view in different place you, have to do it manually according to specific LayoutManager rules.

Comment: thanx for answering atleast... but according to "fillafter" documentation, it will be drawn to new place... anyways, so what can i do to rotate a textview???

Comment: What I'm saying is view shows up in the different place, but is not in the different place if you want to click it. To do what you want, you have to use animation listener and move your view to another place after animation is finished.

Comment: That exactly what i was searching, now if it was moving the view or disappearance of view, i would have done alpha or x or y but here is the case of rotation and i cant figure out how to rotate a textview.